# Geochart Not Showing Small Provinces

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I have problem using geochart for displaying small provinces in my country, the province is Jakarta.
Later I want to create a map like this http://www.olx.co.id/ using geochart, 
When I'm using marker to display the area, it show but when I'm not using the province is dissapear

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Provinces', 'Popularity'],
              ['Jawa Barat', 200],
              ['Jawa Tengah', 300],
              ['Jawa Timur', 400],
              ['Bali', 500],
              ['Jakarta', 600], // this now show
              ['Aceh', 700]
          ]);

      var options = {
          region: 'ID',
          resolution: 'provinces',
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
```

like this : http://jsfiddle.net/x42hfd7e/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you type in the ISO 3166-2 code for Jakarta Special Capital Region, 'ID-JK', as the 'Province' then it will work. See below:

```
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Provinces', 'Popularity'],
          ['Jawa Barat', 200],
          ['Jawa Tengah', 300],
          ['Jawa Timur', 400],
          ['Bali', 500],
          ['ID-JK', 600],
          ['Aceh', 700]
          ]);
```

Please see my revision of the JSfiddle here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/x42hfd7e/1/

For a list of ISO 3166-2:ID codes, please see the "Table of Provinces" here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provinces_of_Indonesia).